# Object Expected Error only in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I keep on getting object expected in IE. This is the Javascript code where I think the problem is:

```
 $('#rv-sidebar-decline-all').click(function () {
        PageModuleContext.sendMessage("declineAll", null, this.handleMessage);
```

and this is its CSS.

```
#rv-sidebar-decline-all {
    cursor              : default;
    height              : 8px;
    width               : 8px;
    background-position : left top;
    background-image    : url({{:declineAll}});
}
```

Basically once this background image is clicked an event is supposed to happen. I get a popup which says Object Expected but if I want to continue running the script. When I click yes on the popup the event happens after that.

Comment: What is the code of the `sendMessage` function?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan may be onto something that `null` you're passing in looks suspicious.

Comment: `this.handleMessage` will cause an issue as well. `this` is scoped to jQuery, not the method that called the `click` method.

Comment: but "this" works well with Chrome, and Firefox, and unfortunately due to security reasons I cannot post the sendMessage function @KJPrice